# SpringBoot 2.6.x produces Application Exit Code 1 on Exit

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I recently upgrade my project from SpringBoot 1.5.x to 2.0.x to 2.6.x with Maven 3.8.1 (bundled with Intellij), JDK 11

Everything is working fine, all tests passed, runs fine with bootrun

But when I stop the application (Using IntelliJ [Stop] button) during bootrun, it produces a `Build Failure` with `Application finished with exit code: 1`

Error log is

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.3:run (default-cli) on project MyProject: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.3:run (default-cli) on project MyProject: Application finished with exit code: 1`

How to fix this error or any workaround?

Comment: First try to run the application on plain command line without Maven plugin... Which JDK version, Maven version etc. do you use? Furthermore it would be helpful having a logging output of the application...

Comment: I am running it with bootrun on java 11

Answer (score 0):

IDEs doesn't show the full error description for this case.

If you are using packing type as war then deploy the war into any external webserver (Ex: Tomcat) directly. Probably you can see the full error stack trace.

In my case I tried the same way, found issue on circular dependency and resolved it.